# Force update on a API-triggered Text Message from Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, mobileconnect, sms

I have a heavily used SMS Template configured in Mobile Connect in which I sometimes have to modify the included Ampscript. While doing so today I discovered a new alert upon clicking the `Save` button in the interface.

[image]

I confirmed and it seemed that the interface was trying to update the message, but finally I got this error message:

[image]

I'm trying to roll the dice and save, but since there's incoming API traffic using this message, the message is not getting updated. Trying repeatedly or waiting for the hours with less traffic is problematic, so I'm wondering if anyone knows if we can somehow force this update. There does not seem to be a REST API method of updating the contents of a message of this type.

Copying the message (and changing the other system to target the new message instead of this one) is outside of the question. The workaround to this issue is obviously moving the content of this message to a code snippet, but that would still require updating this message.